# check if flutter future function works?

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

hello iam new to flutter and i want to do a register function when the sign up button is pressed but i need to make sure that the function is sucssessfull so here is this code and i want to figure out whether i can check if the future function works if it does ill move to another screen id it don't ill show an error message .

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_custom_clippers/flutter_custom_clippers.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

class Signup extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignupState createState() => _SignupState();
}

class _SignupState extends State<Signup> {
  TextEditingController controllerName = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controllerEmail = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controllerPassword = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controllerYear = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controllerType = TextEditingController();
  void register() {
    var url = "http://msc-mu.com/register.php";
    http.post(url, body: {
      "Full_name": controllerName.text,
      "Email": controllerEmail.text,
      "Password": controllerPassword.text,
      "Year": controllerYear.text,
      "Type": controllerType.text
    });
  }
  String _selectedYear;
  List yearsList = List();
  Future<String> getYears() async {
    final response = await http.get('http://msc-mu.com/getYears.php');
    var resBody = json.decode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      yearsList = resBody;
    });
  }
  String _selectedLevel ;
  List levelList = List() ;
  Future<String> getLevel() async {
    final response = await http.get('http://msc-mu.com/getlevel.php');
    var resBody = json.decode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      levelList = resBody;
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getYears();
    this.getLevel();
    controllerYear.text = _selectedYear;
    controllerType.text = _selectedYear;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: size.height,
          width: double.infinity,
            child: Form(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ClipPath(
                    clipper: OvalBottomBorderClipper(),
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage('images/logo1.png'),
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.9,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 50.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: controllerName,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: false,
                        hintText: 'Full Name',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.idCard,
                          size: 30.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 50.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: controllerEmail,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          filled: false,
                          hintText: 'E-mail Address',
                          prefixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.envelope)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 50.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: controllerPassword,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: false,
                        hintText: 'Password',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.key),
                      ),
                      obscureText: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 50.0),
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      hint: Text('Choose A Year'),
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.caretDown),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                      underline: Container(
                        height: 2,
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      ),
                      items: yearsList.map((item) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: Text(item['name']),
                          value: item['name'].toString(),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (yearVal) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedYear = yearVal;
                          controllerYear.text = _selectedYear;
                        });

                      },
                      value: _selectedYear,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0 , horizontal: 50.0),
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      hint: Text('Choose A Role'),
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.caretDown),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                      underline: Container(
                        height: 2,
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      ),
                      items: levelList.map((item) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: Text(item['levelname']),
                          value: item['levelname'].toString(),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (levelVal) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedLevel = levelVal;
                          controllerType.text = _selectedLevel;
                        });

                      },
                      value: _selectedLevel,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          setState(() {
                            if(((controllerName.text.isNotEmpty) &&
                                (controllerPassword.text.isNotEmpty) &&
                                (controllerEmail.text.isNotEmpty) &&
                                (controllerYear.text.isNotEmpty) &&
                                (controllerType.text.isNotEmpty))){
                              register();

                            }else {
                              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                  msg: 'Please fill every thing',
                                  toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                  gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                                  timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                                  textColor: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 16.0);
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 80.0,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                          ),
                          child: Text('Signup',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  letterSpacing: 1.5,
                                  fontSize: 22.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Is your current code not working as you desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the status code, any other status code than 200 is not successful so it will be something like that:

```
if(response.statusCode == 200){
  //Working Code
} else {
  print(response.statusCode); //so you know why it failed
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> YourNextScreen()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `register()` method `async`, and `await` the response :

```
void register() async {
    var url = "http://msc-mu.com/register.php";
    var result = await http.post(url, body: {
      "Full_name": controllerName.text,
      "Email": controllerEmail.text,
      "Password": controllerPassword.text,
      "Year": controllerYear.text,
      "Type": controllerType.text
    });
    // Check the result's data here
  }
```

Comment: may i ask check the result how ?